# Как вывести значение функции

Tags: python

Задача состоит в том, чтобы посчитать сумму цифр числа, например:
54 => 5 + 4 = 9;
1457 => 1 + 4 + 5 + 7 = 17 => 1 + 7 = 8
Когда делал не через return, а через print, то все работало.
Подскажите, как передать значение функции для вывода числа.

```
def func(num):

    if len(str(num)) == 1:
        return num

    elif len(str(num)) == 2:
        k = 0
        for i in str(num):
            k += int(i)
        func(num=k)

    else:
        k = 0
        for i in str(num):
            k += int(i)
        if len(str(k)) >= 2:
            func(num=k)

print(func(952))
```

Comment: рекурсия то тут зачем? Если использовать рекурсию, не понимая рекурсию, то еще и не такое может произойти. Да еще куча веток, которые по сути делают одно и то же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выкидываем все if-elif-else, которые тут совершенно не нужны и добавляем return, который почему-то есть в первой ветке, но нет во всех других

```
def func(num):
    k = 0
    for i in str(num):
        k += int(i)
    return k
```

Если же нужно считать до тех пор, пока результат не станет однозначным, то можно использовать рекурсию:

```
def func(num):
    k = 0
    if num < 10:           # однозначное число
        return num         # считать нечего, результат уже готов
    else:                  # двух- и болеезначное число
        for i in str(num): # считаем сумму цифр
            k += int(i)
        return func(k)     # передаем результат в эту же функцию, чтобы найти сумму цифр нового числа
```

Comment: Я по началу так и писал, но допустим я ввожу число 1457, то результат должен быть таким: 1 + 4 + 5 +7 = 17, затем 1 + 7 = 8. Результатом должна быть число 8

Comment: ну тогда и рекурсия пригодится

Comment: Я был близок, благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `func(num=k)` на 10 и 17 строках напишите `return k`

или замените свою функцию на эту

```
def func(num):
    return sum(int(x) for x in str(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumnum(n: int) -> int:
    result = 0
    while n > 0:
        result += n % 10
        n = n // 10
    return result
```